# Как присвоить std::function<void()> содержимое передаваемой функции c неизвестным заранее количеством параметров?

Tags: c++, функции

Если сейчас функция выглядит вот так:

```cpp
std::function<void()> FAction;

void SimpleButton::addAction(void(*Action)())
{
    FAction = Action;
}
```

и это работает, то нужно что бы функция addAction принимала в себя неизвестное заранее количество аргументов и присваивало функции FAction, т.е. что бы работало

```cpp
button.addAction(some_func, x, y , z, ...);
```

Конечно, вероятно есть возможность создать такую std::function которая способна скопировать любую функцию.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что должна делать `addAction` с этими лишними аргументами??? Как она должна "присваивать" их в `FAction`?

Comment: Сейчас попробую объяснить:
есть класс Button, в нем для удобства есть std::function<void()>, которое выполняется при нажатии.
После создания кнопки на неё должна быть возможность повесить заранее прописанную функцию, НО количество параметров у этой функции может быть различным, поэтому addAction должна принимать функцию (ссылку на неё) и Nное кол-во её параметров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обернуть в анонимный функтор:

```
 template
 <
     typename x_Action
 ,   typename... x_Args
 > void SimpleButton::
 addAction
 (
     x_Action & action
 ,   x_Args... args
 )
 {
      FAction = decltype(FAction)
      {
          [=]()
          {
              action(args...); 
          }
      };
 }
```

Comment: Т.е. как будет выглядеть полная функция addButton и как мне "впихнуть" неопределённое количество параметров?

Comment: Если что, то есть желание, что бы работало и
addAction(some_func, x);
и
addAction(other_func, x, y, z);

Comment: Простите, не работает..
addAction я полностью скопировал, написал в главном файле простенькую 

void button1_print(int x) 
{
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

и далее в int mai():

SimpleButton button1(путьДоКнопки, 100, 100, 100, 300);
button1.addAction(button1_print, 5);

однако при попытке компиляции vs выдаёт

неразрешенный внешний символ 


""public: void __thiscall SimpleButton::addAction<void __cdecl(int),int>(void (__cdecl&)(int),int)" (??$addAction@$$A6AXH@ZH@SimpleButton@@QAEXA6AXH@ZH@Z)"

Comment: Извините что криво написал

Comment: @Dictator_zx Видимо в проекте несколько единиц трансляции и вы добавил код шаблона в один из cpp файлов. Шаблоны необходимо определять в заголовочных файлах.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, было бы разумнее принимать в качестве аргумента `std::function<void()>`. Захватить аргументы пользователь интерфейса сможет самостоятельно, для этого в языке есть лямбды и `std::bind`, позволяющие, в том числе, осуществлять захват по ссылке.

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class SimpleButton{
    std::function<void()> _action;
public:
    void setAction(std::function<void()> fn){
        _action = std::move(fn);
    }

    void click(){
        _action();
    }

};

void printAB(int a, int b){ 
    std::cout<< a << ", " << b << '\n';
}
void test(){
    SimpleButton button;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;
    // a захватывается по значению, b - по ссылке
    button.setAction(std::bind(&printAB, a, std::ref(b)));
    button.click(); // 1, 10
    a = 20;
    b = 200;
    button.click(); // 1, 200

    // аналогично через лямбды
    button.setAction([a, &b]{ 
        std::cout<< a << ", " << b << '\n';
    });
    button.click(); // 20, 200
    a = 300;
    b = 3000;
    button.click(); // 20, 3000
}
```